# Battery backup decreased drastically

Tags: battery

mine is a HP pavillion Dv6-6015tx laptop. I dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04. One glaring problem i have found with ubuntu 13.04 is that it gives me a battery backup of less than an hour. Although, on Windows i get a minimum of 100 minutes backup. Someone please help me out with this problem. I love ubuntu otherwise. 
Thank You.

Comment: Install AMD Radeon HD 6490M Drivers

Comment: @Qasim Post an answer with instructions of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well ,I guess it has to be the switchable graphics thingy.

This should help:

1. Open any terminal.
2. Type in:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   ```

   and then enter your password.
3. Then, just before `exit 0`, type these two lines:

   ```
   chown -R $USER:$USER /sys/kernel/debug
   echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
   ```
4. Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and quit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)
5. Reboot.

You should be fine after this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir.
I will try this out and then get back to you.

Comment: Just an update-- i tried installing the latest drivers from AMD but they didn't work and my system rolled back to the previous (battery hungry) configuration.

Comment: Carried out these tasks, no benefit :(